# Optimizing an update statement - Teradata

Tags: optimization, sql-update, teradata, spool

I'm trying to run the below update, but continue to run into spool space issues.  Is there any way I can optimize?

```
UPDATE  dp_wedw_snd.platinumsaves
SET package_name = (SELECT package_name
                    FROM dp_wedw_snd.selfpaysubs_agid_platsaves
                    WHERE trim(dp_wedw_snd.platinumsaves.esn1) = trim(cast(dp_wedw_snd.selfpaysubs_agid_platsaves.esn as varchar(255)))
                    and     abs(dp_wedw_snd.platinumsaves.shortdate - dp_wedw_snd.selfpaysubs_agid_platsaves.dateasof) = 
                            (select min(abs(dp_wedw_snd.platinumsaves.shortdate - dp_wedw_snd.selfpaysubs_agid_platsaves.dateasof)) 
                            from dp_wedw_snd.platinumsaves, dp_wedw_snd.selfpaysubs_agid_platsaves)
                    )
                    WHERE 
                    EXISTS(SELECT  esn
                    FROM dp_wedw_snd.selfpaysubs_agid_platsaves
                    WHERE trim(dp_wedw_snd.platinumsaves.esn1) =trim(cast(dp_wedw_snd.selfpaysubs_agid_platsaves.esn as varchar(255)))
                    );
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `WHERE EXISTS` clause? Those table names make my head hurt, but it looks to me like it's duplicating the where clause in your select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with this query.

- `from dp_wedw_snd.platinumsaves, dp_wedw_snd.selfpaysubs_agid_platsaves` results in a cross join.
- joins on TRIM are really bad, do you actually have leading blanks in `dp_wedw_snd.platinumsaves.esn1`?
- is `dp_wedw_snd.selfpaysubs_agid_platsaves.esn` a numeric column? Why? And why do you TRIM it, too?

This query should do the same (removing the cross join and rewriting the MIN to QUALIFY):

```
UPDATE dp_wedw_snd.platinumsaves
FROM
 ( 
   SELECT package_name, esn
   FROM dp_wedw_snd.platinumsaves AS ps JOIN dp_wedw_snd.selfpaysubs_agid_platsaves AS sap
     ON TRIM(ps.esn1) = TRIM(CAST(sap.esn AS VARCHAR(255)))
   QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ps.esn1 ORDER BY ABS(ps.shortdate - sap.dateasof)) = 1
 ) AS src
SET package_name = src.package_name
WHERE TRIM(dp_wedw_snd.platinumsaves.esn1) = TRIM(CAST(src.esn AS VARCHAR(255)))
```

Of course you should test if it exactly the same. And check if you can get rid of the TRIM.